# Access refused - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN RabbitMQ Queue

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am trying to use RabbitMQ for posting messages from one application and receiving them in another.
I am able to post messages using localhost.

```
ex:  amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672
```

when i trying to post messages using different Ip getting below mention exception.

```
com.rabbitmq.client.AuthenticationFailureException: ACCESS_REFUSED-Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.
```

sample code:

```
private  Connection getConnection(){
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        final URI uri = URI.create(PropertyReader.read("rabbit.mq.uri").trim());
        factory.setConnectionTimeout(30000);
        factory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true);
        factory.setTopologyRecoveryEnabled(true);
        factory.setNetworkRecoveryInterval(10000);
        factory.setExceptionHandler(new DefaultExceptionHandler());
        factory.setRequestedHeartbeat(360); 
        factory.setUri(uri);

        connection = factory.newConnection();
        LOGGER.info("Rabbit MQ Connection established successfully");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error { }"+e);
    } 
    return connection;
}
```

I need help for this.

using telnet i checked provided Ip.

Comment: using telnet i check the server ip, its connected

Answer (score 3):

The `guest` user can only connect to `localhost` by default: [see the documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html).

> **"guest" user can only connect via localhost**
>
> By default, the guest user is prohibited from connecting to the broker remotely; it can only connect over a loopback interface (i.e. localhost). This applies both to AMQP 0-9-1 and to any other protocols enabled via plugins. Any other users you create will not (by default) be restricted in this way.
>
> This is configured via the loopback_users item in the configuration file.
>
> If you wish to allow the guest user to connect from a remote host, you should set the loopback_users configuration to `none`.
>
> ...

Comment: Hi Gary, Thanks for reply. I changed the username and password, Still am getting same exception.  amqp://****:*****@**.**.**.**.**:5672

Comment: You must still have something mis-configured.

Answer (score 0):

Add the user / pass combination to the factory:

```
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();

    factory.setUsername("user_name");
    factory.setPassword("super_secret_pass");
```